# VB.net add / use HTML/javascript in project

Tags: javascript, html, vb.net

Sorry I was unclear, and hope this will explain better:

I have a Javascript with a lot of calculations. 
And now I need to make a VB.net Windows forms program with the same calculation.
Of course, I can write a class with these calculations, but that will take a lot of time, and can create faults.

As I do not want others to see the javascript I want to add it to my project (project -> add existing...) and the html which will send/receive variables and run the javascript.

So I thought to add a hidden web browser in my program, but how do I run the html/javascript (what is the URL)?

If you need more infomation, please let me know....

I hope you can guide me in the right direction.

Comment: HTML/JAVA or HTML/JAVASCRIPT?

Comment: Question unclear, be more specific.

Comment: Please provide a FULL and CLEAR explanation of the problem.  *"my VB.NET project"* is vague.  How you use things depends on the specific technology you're using.  Is it a web app or Windows?  If Windows, is it Windows Forms or WPF?  Etc.  It sounds like you want basically run a web site inside your Windows app, which doesn't really make sense.  You can load pages from a web site hosted elsewhere but then you wouldn't have the HTML and JavaScript files in your project.

Comment: java is to javascript as ham is to hampster

Comment: In order for the web browser to view your page either write it to a file and use its path as the URL, or load it in memory and set the web browser's [`DocumentText` property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.webbrowser.documenttext).

Comment: If I write it to a file, it probably cannot access the javascript......?

Answer (score 0):

This is *really* the wrong way to do all of this but yes, it's possible.  If you embed a Win Forms WebBrowser control you can navigate to the HTML page and call the underlying java-script with WebBrowser1.Document.InvokeScript("funcSUM", Parameters) after you have loaded the page.

First, you'll want to tie something into WebBrowser1_DocumentCompleted event trigger to avoid trying to run the script before it has loaded.  Note: it's probably best to simply hard-code the URL in the designer but if you wish to trigger the page load differently you'll want to ignore the first page-load of "about:blank"

```
    Private Sub WebBrowser1_DocumentCompleted(sender As Object, e As WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs) Handles WebBrowser1.DocumentCompleted
    If WebBrowser1.Url.ToString <> "about:blank" Then
        Button1.Enabled = True
    End If
End Sub
```

I created a simple HTML/Javascript page with a sum function:

```
<HTML>
Body of HTML
</HTML>

<script>
function funcSUM(num1,num2)
{
    return "Sum: " + Number(num1 + num2);
}
</script>
```

Then I called that page's Javascript function like this, which simply pops up a messagebox "Sum: 4"

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

    Dim Parameter1 As Object() = {2, 2}
    Dim Response = WebBrowser1.Document.InvokeScript("funcSUM", Parameter1)
    MsgBox(Response.ToString())

End Sub
```